# Issues while executing Armstrong number program

Tags: java, numbers, solution

I am trying out a code that finds out whether a number entered is Armstrong or not. Here is the Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Arm {
    int a, b, c;

    void m1() {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int number = obj.nextInt();
        number = (100 * a) + (10 * b) + (1 * c);
        if ((a * a * a) + (b * b * b) + (c * c * c) == number) {
            System.out.println("number is armstrong");
        } else {
            System.out.println("number is not armstrong");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Arm obj = new Arm();
        obj.m1();
    }
}
```

Here the value of a,b and c comes out to be zero. But that is not the correct result. Say if we enter a number `345`. Then `a`,`b` and `c` should be 3, 4 and 5 respectively. 
Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you calculate a, b, c.

To find a,b,c we repeatedly divide by `10` and get the remainder by `modulus`.

```
int digit = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(num > 0)
{
 digit = num % 10;
 sum += Math.pow(digit, 3);
num = num/10;
}
```

**Why do we use `/` and `%`**

Consider `345`.

Now to get the last digit what can be done?

What does a modulus return? The remainder, so If we perform `%10` we get the last digit.

```
345 % 10 = 5
```

Now we want the second last digit.

So we divide the number by 10, so we get the quotient

```
345 / 10 = 34
```

Now again if we can perform the modulus we get the `4` and so on..

**What does 100 * a + 10 * b + 1 * c do?**

That is used to get a number if we have the individual digits.

Suppose we have 3, 4, 5 we know that we get `345` out of it but how do we do it?

```
3 * 100 = 300
4 * 10 = 40
5 * 1 = 5
-----------
300 + 40 + 5 = 345
```

Now to complete your whole program.

```
public boolean isAmg(int num)
{
   int digit = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   int copyNum = num; //used to check at the last 
   while(num > 0)
   {
      digit = num % 10;
      sum += Math.pow(digit, 3);
      num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum == copyNum;
}
```

Comment: void m1() {
  Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number");
  int number = obj.nextInt();
   c=(number%10);
   b=((number/10)%10);
   a=(((number/10)/10));   
  if((a*a*a)+(b*b*b)+(c*c*c)==number){
   System.out.println("Number is Armstrong");
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("Number is not Armstrong");
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Arm obj = new Arm();
  obj.m1();
 }

Comment: @VIvek what If I gave a 1234? a number which is more that 3 digits?

Comment: void m(){
Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int number=obj.nextInt();
int sum=0;
int lop=number;
int digit=0;
while(number>0){
 digit=number%10;
 sum=(int)(sum+Math.pow(digit, 3));
 number=number/10;
 }
if(sum==lop){
 System.out.println("Number is Armstrong");
}
else{
 System.out.println("Number is not Armstrong");
}

Comment: i got your code. Thanks. But can u tell me what happens when this line from my previous code is executed; number = (100 * a) + (10 * b) + (1 * c); Here the value of a,b and c are coming zero no matter what number we have inserted.

Comment: Becasue you never assigned a, b, c from that number.

Comment: ok. I thought it will itself calculate the value of a,b,c according to the number.